# cocos2d and restkit crash on request

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, restkit

trying to get used to restkit at the moment and im having an issue getting it to work within a cocos2d template project. All my restkit code works fine if i create a standard viewcontroller project without any cocos2d but when i try add it to my cocos2d project it crashed in the same place everytime

```
- (NSString*)cacheKey {
if (_method == RKRequestMethodDELETE) {
    return nil;
}
NSString* compositCacheKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d-%@", self.URL, _method, [_URLRequest HTTPBody]];
return [compositCacheKey MD5];
```

it crashes on the return call above within RKRequest.m.

anyone had any issues working with both restkit and cocos2d together? if its even possible and what i need to look out for to make it work? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is probably unable to find the MD5 method because the NSString+MD5.m file was not linked.

If you followed the setup instructions for RestKit correctly, you should have added "-ObjC -all_load" to the "Other Linker Flags" setting in your project Build Settings.

If you are missing this setting, add it.

Now click on the target you are trying to build, and go to its Build Settings. Search again for the "Other Linker Flags" setting, and give it a value of $(inherited).

Now do a clean recompile and your requests should work.

Comment: cool ill check this out when i get home from work and tick you correct if it works. I managed to get what i needed working anyway from creating the standard viewcontroller project and adding the cocos2d lib to that directly and then add restkit. Il still check ur answer though as it would be good for future reference for myself to have working with cocos2d initially.